# Copy new records from datatable and identify changes in old records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, remote-server

Assume there are two tables: `Remote_table` and `My_table`.

`Remote_table` has 6 columns:

```
PROJECT   JOB_TYPE   MONTH  YEAR**       HOURS     IS_DELETED
134393     70         1       2013      30     0
134393     70         2       2013      50     0
134393     70         3       2013      80     0
134393     70         10      2012      10     0
134393     70         11      2012      0      0
134393     70         12      2012      15     0
```

`My_table` is a copy of `remote_table`.

I tried to copy only the new records from the `remote_table` by this query:

```
SELECT    *
FROM [remote_DB].[LudanProjectManager].[dbo].Remote_table            
EXCEPT           
SELECT    *
FROM My_table
```

It works OK but I get a duplicate primary key exception when changes have been made on the `remote_table` on the hours column.

Can anyone think of a way to copy only the new records from `remote_table` and if changes has been made on old records, to identify them and update the `my_table` to correspond?

Comment: You can try Upsert or Merge statement.

Comment: Maybe you should use 'exist in' instead of EXCEPT. The EXCEPT command compares ALL columns and that is why you get duplicate key when there are updates in the hours column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008, you can use [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) :

```
MERGE INTO My_table AS TGT
USING Remote_table AS SRC
  ON TGT.PROJECT = SRC.PROJECT, -- This is the matching condition. 
     TGT.YEAR    = SRC.YEAR,
   ---
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT(PROJECT, JOB_TYPE, MONTH, YEAR, HOURS, IS_DELETED)
  VALUES(SRC.PROJECT, SRC.JOB_TYPE, SRC.MONTH, SRC.YEAR, SRC.HOURS,
         SRC.IS_DELETED);
```

Note that:

- The matched and unmatched rows are determined based on the coditions specified in the `ON` clause, may be you need to restrict the matching rows using extra conditions `, TGT.Year = SRC.TGT, ..` or just matched on the `PROJECT` field only using `ON TGT.PROJECT = SRC.PROJECT`.
- You have to end the `MEREGE` statement with a semicolon. It is mandatory.
- In the `INSERT` statement there was no `INTO TableName` because the name of the target table is already defined in the `MERGE` clause.

Comment: here when matched then he has to update and when not matched insert as new record

Comment: @AnandPhadke Sorry I missed that. Fixed now

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 MERGE INTO My_table T
USING 
    Remote_table R
    ON T.PROJECT    = R.PROJECT   
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
       T.JOB_TYPE=R.JOB_TYPE
       T.MONTH  =R.MONTH  
       T.YEAR =R.YEAR
       T.HOURS =R.HOURS
       T.IS_DELETED=R.IS_DELETED
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (T.PROJECT,T.JOB_TYPE,T.MONTH,T.YEAR,T.HOURS,T.IS_DELETED)
    VALUES (R.PROJECT,R.JOB_TYPE,R.MONTH,R.YEAR,R.HOURS,R.IS_DELETED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Identify new:

```
SELECT * FROM [remote_DB].[LudanProjectManager].[dbo].Remote_table RT
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM My_table MT WHERE MT.PROJECT=RT.PROJECT
)
```

Identify changes:

```
SELECT * FROM [remote_DB].[LudanProjectManager].[dbo].Remote_table RT
INNER JOIN My_table MT ON RT.PROJECT=MT.PROJECT
WHERE RT.JOB_TYPE   <> MT.OB_TYPE
OR    RT.MONTH      <> MT.MONTH  
OR    RT.YEAR       <> MT.YEAR
OR    RT.HOURS      <> MT.HOURS 
OR    RT.IS_DELETED <> MT.IS_DELETED
```